# Making aptitude work properly through a proxy invoked with sudo

Tags: shell, debian, proxy, aptitude

I use Debian 6.
I'm sitting behind a proxy, so I configured Debian to use that proxy. Browsing and any HTTP and FTP activity through GUI works OK.

I wanted to update my package repository so I typed in a shell:

```
sudo aptitude
```

then if I try to update the repo (pressing 'u') aptitude stops while trying to reach debian's FTP server, and this action will eventually time out.

But if it try:

```
$ su
# aptitude
```

updating works.

What is the difference between the two invocation? The `$http_proxy` and `$ftp_proxy` environment variables exist in both shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **su** command starts another shell as root (or whomever if you supply a username and correct password).  This shell gets all the normal environment variables, which of course includes the HTTP_PROXY and FTP_PROXY variables.  Thus it works.

The **sudo** command REMOVES ALL environment variables except for a specifically chosen subset... which of course does NOT include the HTTP_PROXY & FTP_PROXY variables, thus your commands fail.

You can make **sudo** keep the *_PROXY variables by editing the sudoers config file, using the **visudo** command (of course).

Adding the following will make *sudo* keep the values of HTTP_PROXY & FTP_PROXY:

```
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy ftp_proxy https_proxy HTTP_PROXY FTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY"
```

Coincidentally, if you add DISPLAY & HOME to that list, you can use gui programs with sudo too (they need the DISPLAY variable to connect)

```
Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY HOME"
```

You can even just add those two lines, like that.   (The **+=** is the key here)  Remember to add these lines towards the end of the file, since in the first few lines it usually sets the '*env_keep*' variable with a straight '**=**', which erases any previous value.

Comment: geez, I need to read documentation :-) thanks, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this myself and finally went with the solution proposed on Ask Ubuntu:
[apt-get does not work with proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy/23669#23669)

> If setting `http_proxy` does not work try editing `apt.conf`. In
>   Ubuntu `apt.conf` is fragmented in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` directory.
>   In this directory edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu`:
>
> ```
> APT {
>   Acquire {
>       http {
>           Proxy "http://user:password@server:port";
>       };
>   };
> };
> ```

Comment: This is a fixed setting. I tried this, and it is useless for notebooks that move among different networks (it won't fall back to direct connection if it cannot find the proxy)